# PendingDeprecationWarning on django / tastypie

Tags: django, python-3.x, tastypie

I am trying to set a pretty straightforward example of a REST service using tastypie, however I am getting a PendingDeprecationWarning.

Here is the error message appearing on the browser

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/api/myapp_resource
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: PendingDeprecationWarning
Exception Value:    
commit_on_success is deprecated in favor of atomic.
Exception Location: /home/pkaramol/Workspace/django-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py in commit_on_success, line 448
Python Executable:  /home/pkaramol/Workspace/django-env/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.3.2
Python Path:    
['/home/pkaramol/Workspace/django-env/restserver',
 '/home/pkaramol/Workspace/django-env/lib/python3.3',
 '/home/pkaramol/Workspace/django-env/lib/python3.3/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/pkaramol/Workspace/django-env/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.3',
 '/usr/lib/python3.3/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/pkaramol/Workspace/django-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages']
```

I am using tastypie 0.11.0

There is not much of a documentation or other reports regarding this error (warning rather) so I would like to ask for suggestions on how to go about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem seems to be solved by changing the decorator of `patch_list()` method (line 2190) in file resources.py file of tastypie

from `@transaction.commit_on_success()`

to `@transaction.atomic()`

Comment: Worked for me too, on Python 2.7.5 and Django 1.6.2.